# Last command exit code comparison in .bashrc

Tags: bash

As all of you probably know, bash can print the last command exit code. This works for me, but I wanted to improve it by adding an if statement which checks if `$?` was `0`. If it is `0` print the code in white, and if it is different, print it in red. Unfortunately this does not seem to work:

```
if [ $? == "0" ]; then
        PS1=${PS1}'$(echo ${?})'
else
        PS1=${PS1}'\e[1;31m\]$(echo ${?})'
fi
```

I also tried:

```
if [ $(echo $?) == "0" ]; then
        PS1=${PS1}'$(echo ${?})'
else
        PS1=${PS1}'\e[1;31m\]$(echo ${?})'
fi
```

also:

```
if [ $(echo ${?}) == "0" ]; then
        PS1=${PS1}'$(echo ${?})'
else
        PS1=${PS1}'\e[1;31m\]$(echo ${?})'
fi
```

None of them working.

Somehow variable is always 0, therefore printed in white.

How is it possible that I can print exit code, but cannot examine it with `"if"` ? Is this a bash limitation, or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: `==` vs. `-eq` when using `[`.

Comment: The `[` command sets the value of `$?` to *its* exit status, overwriting the exit status of whatever command's exit status it tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `$?` to the PS1.

```
> PS1='PS $ '
> PS $ echo 1 
> 1 
> PS $ PS1='PS $? $ '
> PS 0 $ false 
> PS 1 $ true
> PS 0 $
```

If you want to change color, you would have to do it inside PS1, not statically... Also note that `$?` will change it's value, so you need to save it.

```
PS1=${PS1}'$(ret=$?; if [ "$ret" -ne 0 ]; then printf "\e[1;31m\]"; fi; printf "%d" "$ret")'
```

Answer (score 0):

`$?` is the exit status of the *last* command. If you execute some command, for instance `[ … = … ]`, then `$?` changes. Example:

```
myCmd
echo $? # prints exit status of myCmd
echo $? # prints exit status of echo 

myCmd
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    echo $? # prints exit status of `[`, here 0 
else
    echo $? # prints exit status of `[`, here 1 
fi
```

Store the exit status of `myCmd` in a separate variable if you want to access it later.

```
myCmd
exitStatus=$?
echo $exitStatus # prints exit status of myCmd
echo $exitStatus # prints exit status of myCmd
```

By the way: `"$(echo ${?})"` is overly complicated; just `"$?"` is better in every way.